# how do i fix the mime type of css

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm creating a login form for my spring app. i configured the filterchain and endpoint for the custom login page. hwoever when i run the application it returns the login page without styling.

here is my security configuration:

```
 public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws  Exception{

    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
           .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("Implementation/user/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/LoginPage").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/LoginPage")
            .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")
            .permitAll();


    return httpSecurity.build();
```

and this is my login controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/LoginPage")
    public String login(){
        return ("Login & Sign-up");
    }
```

and this is the error i get on the browser console:

```
fused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/LoginPage' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

i noticed that it says can't apply style from the end point and not the actual css file. i do not know if that is related to the problem.

i'd like to note that i ran into this problem before and fixed it by removing then installing the security dependancies. it didn't do anything this time.